# I would like to do is have the login and signup form as a single form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using devise for authentication.
If the email already exists it logs the user in.
If the email does not exist then it creates a new user using those credentials.
there should be only one submit button and a field for email and password.

Comment: This is a sql related question ... where are you storing user credentials ?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question please? It depends on what credentials you want User to provide while signup and signin, right?

Comment: i storing user credentials in mysql database.

Comment: i want the login form, but if the user enters a non-existing email it is automatically registered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is possible for that have to write condition for that in your controller

for example

```
def create
 @user = @user.find_or_create_by(params[:user])
 ....
 ....
end
```

or

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user])
  unless @user.present?
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.valid?
      ...
    else 
      ...
   end
 end
end
```

or # for devise - in registration controller

```
def create
  @user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])
  if @user.present? 
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  else
    if resource.save
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
       ...
       ...
      else
       ...
       ...
      end
    else
      ...
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I am using Devise, and how to call its methods?

Comment: you can write this in registration controller or session controller.

Comment: may be create a new controller which call methods Devise controller?

Comment: try - i added new action in last - write that action in registration controller.

Answer (score 0):

You create a form for `user_session` that goes to `create` action.

On the server side somewhere, you call this from your `create` action. I would put in a method of `UserSession`.

```
if User.find_by_email(email)
  # check credentials
else
  # create user
end
```

Comment: how to use devise method for login or sign up?